# How apply mutate to only a subset of rows, but still creating a new column for each observation?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with 60 observations of sequential investment decisions made by some participants. Each investment decision is a number between 0 and 100. My dataframe is organized that way:

```
subjet_id | period |  invest  |
1      |  1     | 42%         |
1      |  2     | 13%         |
1      |  ...   | 72%         |
1      |  60    | 18%         |
2      |  1     | 52%         |
2      |  ...   | 42%         |
2      |  60    | 18%         |
3      |  1     | 25%         |
```

I know how to create a new column with the mean of investment for each subject:

```
dataframe = dataframe %>% group_by(subjet_id) %>% mutate(mean_invest = mean(invest))
```

Now I want to split my periods between "short run" (periods 1 to 30) and "long run" (periods 31 to 60). I would like to have one new row for the investment mean of each participant for both short run and long run. I want something like that (numbers are not accurate):

```
subjet_id | period |  invest  | invest_mean | short_run_mean | long_run_mean  |
1      |  1     | 42%         | 25%         | 15%            | 25%            |
1      |  2     | 13%         | 25%         | 15%            | 25%            |
1      |  ...   | 72%         | 25%         | 15%            | 25%            |
1      |  60    | 18%         | 35%         | 45%            | 25%            |
2      |  1     | 52%         | 35%         | 45%            | 25%            |
2      |  ...   | 42%         | 35%         | 45%            | 25%            |
2      |  60    | 18%         | 35%         | 45%            | 25%            |
3      |  1     | 25%         | 30%         | 20%            | 30%            |
```

The problem is that I can not just do a  `filter(periods < 30)`
and a  `mutate (short_run_mean = mean(invest))` because I will have short_run_mean values only for periods < 30 :

```
subjet_id | period |  invest  | invest_mean | short_run_mean | long_run_mean  |
1      |  1     | 42%         | 25%         | 15%            | ---            |
1      |  2     | 13%         | 25%         | 15%            | ---            |
1      |  ...   | 72%         | 25%         | 15%            | ---            |
1      |  60    | 18%         | 35%         | ---            | 25%            |
2      |  1     | 52%         | 35%         | 45%            | ---            |
2      |  ...   | 42%         | 35%         | 45%            | ---            |
2      |  60    | 18%         | 35%         | ---            | 25%            |
3      |  1     | 25%         | 30%         | 20%            | ---            |
```

Therefore, I would like to apply the mean function only to a subset of my dataframe, and add the result to each line as a new variable.

Any idea of how I can do that with regular R functions (I know I can use for loops and stuff like that, but I am looking for a functional solution!).

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- read.table(textConnection('subjet_id | period |  invest  
1      |  1     | 0.42         
1      |  2     | 0.13          
1      |  60    | 0.18        
2      |  1     | 0.52           
2      |  60    | 0.18         
3      |  1     | 0.25         
'),header=T,sep='|')

library(dplyr)

df2 <- df %>%
group_by(subjet_id) %>%
mutate(invest_mean=mean(invest)) %>%
ungroup %>%
mutate(period_type=ifelse(period>=1 & period<=30,'short_run','long_run')) %>%
group_by(subjet_id,period_type) %>%
mutate(short_run_mean=ifelse(period_type=='short_run',mean(invest),NA)) %>%
mutate(long_run_mean=ifelse(period_type=='long_run',mean(invest),NA)) %>%
ungroup %>%
select(-period_type)

df2
```

**output;**

```
  subjet_id period invest invest_mean short_run_mean long_run_mean
      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>       <dbl>          <dbl>         <dbl>
1         1      1   0.42       0.243          0.275         NA   
2         1      2   0.13       0.243          0.275         NA   
3         1     60   0.18       0.243         NA              0.18
4         2      1   0.52       0.35           0.52          NA   
5         2     60   0.18       0.35          NA              0.18
6         3      1   0.25       0.25           0.25          NA
```